# Why call macro in this way?

Tags: c++

I read larbin source code recently. But I have a doubt. I the global.h file define the global class, at the end of this file have a macro like this:

```
#define setPoll(fds, event) \
global::pollfds[global::posPoll].fd = fds; \
global::pollfds[global::posPoll].events = event; \
global::posPoll++
```

But in the fetch/fetchPipe.cc file, call this macro like this:

```
global::setPoll(n, POLLOUT);
```

The question is why use global:: to call this macro? I think use

```
setPoll(n, POLLOUT);
```

is ok. Any body can tell me why?

Comment: `global::setPoll` looks like a bug to me. It would expand to `global::global::pollfds[`...

Comment: @eharvest C++, C doesn't accept `global::whatever`.

Comment: @eharvest: Technically C++, since there's apparently a class, but spiritually C since it uses macros instead of inline methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The source code is a complete mess, it won't even compile. It seems that `global.h` has been changed between version 2.2.2 and the current version 2.6.3 without addressing those changes in `fetch/fetchPipe.h`. Also have a look at those include statements in `global.cc`:

```
#include <iostream.h> // iostream.h?
#include <unistd.h>   // twice, see below
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>   // mixing C++ and C libraries
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <unistd.h>
    ...
```

This code is outdated and not standard C++. There are several other things wrong. But back to your question: yes, `setPoll(n, POLLOUT);` should be sufficient. Using `global::setPoll` will not result in a bug, since this will expand to

```
global::global::pollfds[global::posPoll].fd = fds;
global::pollfds[global::posPoll].events = event;
global::posPoll++;
```

and `global` is a `struct` (see [Mike Seymour's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11721837/why-call-macro-in-this-way/11722217#comment15552512_11722217)).

Comment: You are right, it's not standard c++. I surprise is that it can compile ok with global::setPoll(n, POLLOUT) at gcc version 4.5.2 (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.5.2-8ubuntu4)

Comment: `global::global::pollfds` is not an error if `global` is a class; a class-name is injected into the class's scope, so `global`, `global::global` and `global::global::global::global::global` are all equivalent.

Comment: @MikeSeymour: Accidentally misread the declaration of `global` and thought it was a namespace. My fault.